# How to convert multiple rows into single row but with different column names in postgressql

Tags: sql, postgresql

My resultant out is this using `case when` in postgres

```
id   name    amount1      amount2       amount3
1     abc    10           null          null
1     abc    null         5             null
1     abc    null         null          40
```

I want my output as:

```
id   name    amount1      amount2       amount3
1    abc     10           5             40
2    aaa     90           20            10
```

Comment: The input and output are having the same column name. I understand that the first record is an aggregate of abc with a sum of each corresponding field (sum(amount1) yields amount1), where the value defaults to 0 if it was `null`. Yet, I do not see how your input should yield the second record from your output, so I will assume in my answer that you are just not giving us your full input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate using `group by` and `coalesce` `null` values to 0:

```
select id, name, sum(coalesce(amount1, 0)) as amount1, sum(coalesce(amount2, 0)) as amount2, sum(coalesce(amount3, 0)) as amount3
from yourtable
group by id, name
```

I understand you have a `case when` and your input in the question is the result of that. Without knowing more about your tables, the best I can suggest is to replace `yourtable` in the query above with `(<yourquery>) t` and of course, you need to replace `<yourquery>` with your actual query.

See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e568d0/6

Test DB:

```
create table yourtable(
    id int,
    name varchar(8),
    amount1 int,
    amount2 int,
    amount3 int
);

insert into yourtable(id, name, amount1, amount2, amount3)
values
(1, 'abc', 10, null, null),
(1, 'abc', null, 5, null),
(1, 'abc', null, null, 40),
(2, 'aaa', 90, 20, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `group by` and the aggregate function `max()` ( use `sum()` if you want to `sum` your data by *id* ) :

```
select id, max(name) as name, max(amount1) as amount1, max(amount2) as amount2, max(amount3) as amount3
from mytable
group by id
```